# Indicator of new created Contacts

Tags: android, contactscontract

Is there any indicator besides RawContacts.VERSION and RawContacts.DIRTY that tells me if a new contact has been created?

Right now I check the contactdatabase for "DIRTY"-contacts and then if the VERSION field is greater two it's a changed contact otherwise it is a new one.

But now I have the problem that if my SyncAdapter fails to sync this new contact due to network problems or server problems I could miss it, if the user change the contact again, befor my syncadapter gets a second chance to upload it. Because then the VERSION field will be greater than two and my syncadapter fails to recognize that this contact is a new one.

I checked the references twice, but can't find any field that would indicate it.

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Cheers,
Ali3n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the missing puzzlepiece: RawContacts.SOURCE_ID

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html) says:

> String that uniquely identifies this row to its source account.
>   Typically it is set at the time the raw contact is inserted and never
>   changed afterwards. The one notable exception is a new raw contact: it
>   will have an account name and type (and possibly a data set), but no
>   source id. This indicates to the sync adapter that a new contact needs
>   to be created server-side and its ID stored in the corresponding
>   SOURCE_ID field on the phone.SOURCE_ID field on the phone.